# how to find out whether nsurclconnection's encoding is gzip'ed or not

Tags: ios, http, gzip, nsurlconnection

is there way to figure out whether your nsurlconnection is actually gzip now and not the typical one, because i want to compare the differences in times. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` method `-connection:didReveiveResponse:` you can check the header fields for `Content-Encoding` like:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"%@", (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields]);
}
```

Comment: Same for sendAsynchronousRequest - look at the NSURLResponse.